# should I buy this drone?

Tags: raspberry-pi, beginner

I am a beginner and wanted to buy myself a little drone kit to learn to program it. I was thinking about a raspberry pi 4b and pixhawk drone, but I don't know what to buy.
I saw this thing on amazon, and I know that it is quite old but it is very cheap `https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B09SZ74YFK/ref=ox_sc_act_image_1?smid=AQQD305QEV0YZ&psc=1`
and I would add by myself the raspberry pi 4b and the rasberry pi camera module `https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B01ER2SKFS/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=AYJCVVRX88QTX&psc=1`
I was thinking to do it like in this yt video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB9YyG2V-nA&list=PL_2ZLLWNjKFHxIDptncuVNmTsvjAdAjM7&index=3`
I would like to program it with python. Is this good, if not does anybody have an alternative in the same price range? Am I missing some elements that I will need to buy to control my drone? I have a total budget of 500 euros without the RC since I would prefer to control the drone entirely with python scripts

Answer (score 0):

I would **avoid** this kit:

- its pretty outdated hardware
- the arms are made of thin plastic, this is likely going to break when crashed

if you *don't* care about the plastic problem, you can get the frame without the hardware (so you can buy more modern one) for cheap on ali-express (its called F450).

if you spend a bit more time searching ali-e for comparable frames, you might find one of these kits: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004864316433.html it's marginally better than the F450 kit, mostly because its using carbon arms.

I'd like to point out to you, that you *will* need rc equipment, as full autonomous flight will need a lot of paperwork (I'm assuming EU rules as you posted french links) if you ever want to fly that outside of a hall, while if you want to fly that in the open category (de-facto category for hobby), you need to be able to control the drone.

that said, you want that ability either way - and if it's only to shut down the motors after your Python code crashed the drone full-speed in the next bush.

Generally. I would recommend connecting with builders in your region, for advice & help, and because you might be able to get a few used parts for cheap.

PS: one of the best drone-part stores i buy from is in france: https://www.drone-fpv-racer.com/en/ while they aren't likely to have the kind of frame you are looking for, they should have most other things you could need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked a bit Alie express and the link that you gave me ```https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004864316433.html```  So it has a carbon frame, telemetry module and plenty of other stuff. It is also very cheap and has a lot of components. But I never bought anything on Alie express, is it trust worthy? Also there is a lot of different packs, which one would you recommend (probably one with a telemetry module) but which one?

Comment: is ali-e trustworthy: well, its a sales platform with a bunch of different sellers, and i have heard of people having trouble - myself, the only issues i ever had were easily solved by requesting to get my money back.It does take some time to be delivered from china though.

as for which pack: you have to check what suits  your usecase best, i probably would go a totally different route with a lot more customization

Answer (score 0):

Python and a Raspberry Pi aren't really a good match for a drone. The Pi is a complete computer, and thus has a lot of overhead. It isn't solely focused on your programme, and can pause briefly to handle other tasks. Similarly, Python is an interpreted language and not ideal for a real-time system. I'll add that popular flight controller software (like BetaFlight or INav) are also mature products with lots of complex features that make them hard to understand.

I recommend looking at [dRehmFlight](https://github.com/nickrehm/dRehmFlight) (pronounced dream-flight). The code is simple and it runs on a Teensy, which is small, cheap and light-weight.

Comment: the question was about a drone with pixhawk and raspberry pi, not for raspberry pi as flight controller - in a combination like that the pixhawk is acting as the flight controller and doing the realtime job, the rapsberry pi then communicates with the flight controller - if their goal is to build something that needs to computational power of the sbc, for example to work with map data, trigger a payload when reaching an area etc. then this is a setup that should work fine, especially for a beginner